# Why is there vertical padding in a Label?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label

I have a problem understanding where vertical padding in a widget comes from. The following code

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

currentfont = 'Muli'
root = tk.Tk()
# a single frame in root - the prod version has several
timestr = tk.Frame(root)
# the green background is added to show the limits of the Label
timeh = tk.Label(timestr, background='green', text="21")
timem = tk.Label(timestr, background='green', text="45")
timeh.grid(row=0, column=0)
timem.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N)
timem.configure(font=(currentfont, 170))
font = tkFont.Font(family=currentfont, size=250, weight="bold")
timeh.configure(font=font)
timestr.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
tk.mainloop()
```

produces

[image]

Why is there vertical padding above and below the glyphs? Is there a way to make them vertically fit into the window, similarly to how they fit horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding is likely part of the font, not the widget. Fonts need space above and below the space for average sized  characters to make room for [ascenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_%28typography%29) and [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descenders). The larger the font, the more space that is needed . Without the space below, for example, where would the bottom part of a lowercase "g" or "y" go?

Comment: You are right, it seems obvious in retrospection. Is there a way to force the *maximal* height of a window (the rationale being that I will only have numbers, so no need for ascenders and descenders). Or should I open a new question for this?